# Next.js 13 tree shaking not working on component library

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have built a component library using React 18, compiled it with TypeScript and imported it into my Next.js 13.4 project (created with `create-next-app`).

Everything works as expected, except that imports from the entry point of the library (a barrel file re-exporting all my components and utilities) import all the components, inflating the app's bundle size.

The library and app are using the ES Module syntax, and I have added `"sideEffects": false` to both `package.json`s. I have also used `@next/bundle-analyzer`, and saw all components incuded when only one is imported.

Is there something else I need to do to get tree shaking to work, or is it not possible in this situation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find something here?

Comment: @AntonioLaguna Unfortunately not, so I have been importing from each component's individual file, which is quite lengthy and not ideal.

Comment: Do you have something public? I'm going to dive into this as I have a lead already and need to crack this so would love to let you know somehow about this :)

Comment: Do you use 'use client' on those? I've found that to be having issues

Comment: @AntonioLaguna I do use 'use client' on some components. I will share some code when I can.

Comment: Check optimizepackageimports and also try Next 14 if you can and let me know, I found out it did solve the issue for me