# NextJS chunks/pages/_app.js weighs almost 7MB

Tags: next.js, import, bundle

Using `next-bundle-analyzer` I noticed that my bundle sizes were huge due to the "first load shared by all". This is because of the node modules included in app.js (6.62MB):

[image]

As can be seen in the image, this is mostly due to ant-design imports and mapbox-gl, which made no sense to me because these packages are not imported in the `_app.tsx` (note that I'm using Typescript).

After carefully analysing the situation I finally found the culprit. I am importing my generic Button in the 500.tsx (error page) which is included in _app.tsx:

```
//import Button from "@components/elements/Button";
import {Button} from "@components/elements";
```

So this is where it gets really interesting, if I use the line that has been **commented** out, then _app.js weighs just a few kilobytes, but if I use the **uncommented** line then I get the issue from the image above. Seemingly, the bundle includes EVERYTHING in `@components/elements` even though I specifically import only `{Button}`.

The bundler seems to not be able to determine which exports are actually used in the application.

**Importantly** in `src/components/elements` I have an index.tsx file as such:

```
export { default as Button } from './Button'
export { default as Input } from './Input'
export { default as VitumModal } from './Modal'
export { default as VitumSpinner } from './Spinner'
export { default as DynamicTagList } from './DynamicTagList'
export { default as DynamicTable } from './DynamicTable'
export { default as VitumMap } from './Map'
export { default as LocationMap } from './Map/GetLocationMap'
export { default as VitumBadge } from './Badge'
```

As you can see, the `Map` here is obviously the reason mapbox-gl gets imported for example.

Am I doing something wrong here? Should I be defining these exports differently so the bundler understands exactly which component I need?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be defining these exports differently so the bundler understands exactly which component I need?

Yes. The way you import in the commented line is the correct one.

To understand why, we have to keep in mind that the uncommented line uses destructuring, a **convenient** syntax to assign into variables the properties of an object.

But it is just a convenient syntax that internally does that:

```js
import * as elements from "@components/elements";

const Button = elements.Button;
```

As you can see, you are importing the whole object exported by `@components/elements` into your module, and then you assign one property (`Button`) to a constant named `Button`.

You actually probably don't need this "export all" module named `@components/elements`. I don't know your project but I doubt you'll end up using it if you import your dependencies from the modules that expose them instead of this "export all" module. But I may be wrong.

Usually, these kind of modules are used by libraries to expose their public API. For example, here:

https://gitlab.com/nightlycommit/twing/-/blob/main/src/lib.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't need the "export all" as you say, but the reason I have the index.tsx is so that I can import several elements in a single line using destructuring. For example something like this: "import {Form, Select, Input, InputNumber, Result, Spin, message, Tooltip} from "antd";". Since almost all libraries allow for this, and tree shaking works in these cases, isn't there any way that one can implement destructured importing and have the bundler understand which component to import?

Comment: By the way, I think this question from 4 months ago which still lacks an answer has essentially the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76813509/next-js-13-tree-shaking-not-working-on-component-library

Comment: @FabianSvensson at one point, probably tree shaking should clean the bundle, I agree. And I think the destructuring syntax totally permi tree shaking. So maybe something is wrongly configured in your development tool chain.

Comment: I found this post just now which perfectly tackles this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527907/barrel-file-and-tree-shaking?rq=2

The suggested solution says to change the "module" compilerOption to "esnext" in tsconfig.son/jsconfig.json. I already have this and the issue persists, but perhaps it is something configuration related.

I will continue to look into it and see if I can find a solution. Otherwise importing directly as you suggested in your answer works.